# Save drawables in local storage as cache and then read them for a Share_Intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have drawables in my project that i have declared as seperate resource array

```
  public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.ic_bl1,
        R.drawable.ic_bl2,
        R.drawable.ic_bl3,
        R.drawable.ic_bl4,
        R.drawable.ic_bl5,
        R.drawable.ic_ca1,
        R.drawable.ic_ca2,
        R.drawable.ic_ch}
```

I want to save them all in a temp folder on local storage of android(not SD Card)so that I can retrieve them later and send them via a share intent.I have code for share Intent completed

```
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
        //   sharingIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.orca");
            sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Send Via");
            chooserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           sContext.startActivity(chooserIntent);
         //   sContext.startActivity(sharingIntent);

        }
    });
```

I need to pass a Uri of a particular file to be sent,and best way to get it is through saving images in local storage and then retrieving there Uri.I know how to save a single image in cache and then retrieving it.

I can't figure out how to save a list of drawables in a particular folder on local storage and then retrieving there Uris for a use in share intent later.

Comment: You can store image in `BASE64` format in  `SharedPreferences`

Comment: That is the worst advice you can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this code.
But add read and write storage permission.

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/png");
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;

    Drawable mDrawable = imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mDrawable).getBitmap();

    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(mContext.getContentResolver(), mBitmap, "Image Description", null);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Content!!"));

}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.+1 for an amazing answer.Is there a way I can only select particular apps that will appear on the chooser dialog?Or better can I get current open app like a messenger to be chosen automatically when i use shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND)?

Comment: Yes for particular facebook and whatsapp and other social media app but you need to set component and try to find out package name. it will definitely helps you!! Best of luck :)